# Conditional Printing with Netsuite Advanced PDF/HTML Template (Zero Value)

Tags: templates, netsuite, freemarker

I have inherited a custom NetSuite Advanced PDF/HTML Template which is the primary default for the majority of our invoicing.

We would like to have an expenses line **not** print when value is $0.00. Searches online and of Stack Overflow have not provided clear direction. It appears #if/#else might be solution, but I am unclear on how to integrate into the existing code. I have some HTML/CSS experience, but am new to Freemarker.

The current code looks to wrap instructions for printing line items that are not entered as expenses **within** the Billable Expenses instructions?

```
<#if record.item?has_content>
        <#assign totalBillableExpense = 0>
        <table class="itemtable" style="width: 100%; margin-top: 10px;"><!-- start items -->
            <#list record.item as item>
                <#if item_index==0>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th colspan="20" align="left">${item.description@label}</th>
                            <!--th align="center" colspan="3">${item.quantity@label}</th-->
                            <!--th align="right" colspan="4">${item.rate@label}</th-->
                            <th align="right" colspan="4">${item.amount@label}</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </#if>
                <tr>
                    <#if item.custcol_ns_print_pdf?string == "Yes">                      
                        <td colspan="20">          
                            <!--#if item.itemtype?contains("Description") || item.itemtype?contains("Subtotal")-->
                            <!--/#if-->

                          ${item.description}</td>
                            <!--td align="center" colspan="3" line-height="150%">${item.quantity}</td-->
                            <!--td align="right" colspan="4">${item.rate}</td-->
                            <td align="right" colspan="4">${item.amount}</td>
                    </#if>
                    <#if item.description?contains("Total Billable Expenses")>
                        <#assign totalBillableExpense = totalBillableExpense + item.amount>
                    </#if>
                </tr>
            </#list><!-- end items -->
            <tr>
                <td colspan="20">Billable Expenses </td>
                <td align="right" colspan="4">${totalBillableExpense?string.currency}</td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Can you mark out with comments the part you would like excluded? Do you mean don't print a line if its amount is 0 or don't print the whole section?  Or suppress all the potential empty `<tr/>` sections?

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you are asking:

```
<#if totalBillableExpense gt 0>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="20">Billable Expenses </td>
            <td align="right" colspan="4">${totalBillableExpense?string.currency}</td>
        </tr>
</#if>
```

Also to avoid a potential issue with empty `<tr/>` tags you should reformulate this:

```
<tr>
    <#if item.custcol_ns_print_pdf?string == "Yes">    
    ....
   </#if>
   <#if item.description?contains("Total Billable Expenses")>
       <#assign totalBillableExpense = totalBillableExpense + item.amount>
   </#if>
</tr>
```

to something like:

```
<#if item.description?contains("Total Billable Expenses")>
       <#assign totalBillableExpense = totalBillableExpense + item.amount>
</#if>
<#if item.custcol_ns_print_pdf?string == "Yes">
    <tr>
    
    ....
   </tr>
</#if>
```

Comment: Really appreciate that you provided an answer when unclear of the question. Plus you hit it it right on the money and made me look like a wiz rather than the fumbler I am.

Thank you also for pointing out the potential empty tag issue.